# Property of numbers question (Spivak's calculus)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was rereading a part of spivak's calculus and I noticed something :

He offers the following property :

P2 : a+0=0+a=a

Later, he says that we can even prove it using P1 to P3. (P1: associative property of addition P3:a+(-a)=(-a)+a=0)

Basically, he does this :[image]

How can he conclude that 0+x=x with P2 if that's what we're proving ??? Is this allowed ?

Comment: Because 0 is a additive inverse of itself and its unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is slightly more subtle than this, he has proven by these axioms, that if $a+x=a$ then $x=0$, which tells us $a+0=a$ (and $0+a=a$ with practically the same argument).

Comment: Oh, ok, I'm the one who didn't read correctly ^^